# adding different data-id to PHP / HTML loop

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a loop to call posts so I can display posts easily on my website, however... I'm using animate.css to add animations, and a problem I'm now facing is all of these elements have the same data-id so they scroll in at the same time...

I'm very new to PHP and so I don't know if there's a way that I can give each of the divs a different data-id so they scroll in one by one?

Here's my code thus far;

```
<div class="animatedParent animateOnce" data-appear-top-offset='-525' data-sequence='500' style="margin: 40px 0; text-align: center;">
<h2 class="animated bounceInUp" data-id='14' style="text-transform: uppercase;">Recent Events at Pontins!</h2>
    <div class="past-events">
    <?php query_posts('cat=#&posts_per_page=4'); ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="one-fourth animated bounceInLeft" data-id='15'>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('large_wide'); ?>
                </a>
                <h4><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

http://www.stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins-events/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/js/css3-animations.js here's a link to the JS (I'm using 'Jack McCourt - Animate It')

Comment: I see you sent the plugin code, but where are you calling it? where are you initializing that script and giving it the id parameter?

Comment: Would that be from my functions.php file? I've enqueued the script in my functions.php file, and from there I've started adding classes and data-id, data-appear-top-offset and data-sequence as in the tutorial on Jack McCourts website

Comment: ahh ok ok ok, I get it, you're just using classes to let the script know the way you want to animate them.... and do you have an URL to see what you're getting now?

Comment: Yeah, here's a link to the site as it is currently (calling ID as you posted below) and you'll see the recent posts are there, but they don't display anything http://stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins-events/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in the data-id attribute of your div.

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <div class="one-fourth animated bounceInLeft" data-id='<?php echo the_ID(); ?>'>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace data-id value with the current post id, now you have different ids for each element.

```
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="one-fourth animated bounceInLeft" data-id='<?php echo the_ID();?>'>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('large_wide'); ?>
                </a>
                ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I failed to mention I need the data-id, because that calls when to bring in the element (as I understand) and without the data-id (including data-id as in your method) the items are there, but don't show up because they are offset until called by data-id

Comment: What you're facing here is more a javascript problem than a PHP problem. Can you update your question with the Javascript code you're using to animate the elements?